# Error autenticación en nodejs con passport

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, passport

Realizo un login con passport de nodejs, para probar el backend utilizo Insomnia como cliente HTTP y no tengo problema, pero al momento usar el fronend hecho en reactjs tengo situación con el middleware para proteger las rutas pues me da falso, cuando al usar insomnia me da true:

```
//Middleware authentication
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
   //Al usar insomnia req.isAuthenticated() me da true
   //Al usar con frontend me da false
 if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

La ruta donde se hace la autenticación es la siguiente:

`router.route('/signup').post(passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true 
  }));`

Ya verifique que a esta ruta le lleguen los datos y los procese correctamente, de hecho, redirecciona a '/home' pues la autenticación tiene éxito pero no entra a home porque el middleware isAuthenticated da falso, repito, solo cuando intento con el frontend hecho con reactjs

`router.route('/home').get(isAuthenticated,(req, res)=> {
  console.log('Arriving home');

  res.json({message: 'Home'});
})`

gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La situación estaba con al hacer uso de axios del lado del frontend, cuando hacia la petición:

`const answer = await axios.post('http://localhost:3003/signin',newWord,{withCredentials: true});`

agregue las credenciales en true para que del lado del backend me aceptará la petición desde el frontend con axios. Para que funcionará bien, en el backend modifique:

`app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3002'}));`

Como cors me ayuda a la comunicación entre los servidores de backend y frontend, agregue la aceptación de las credenciales.